# Optimize for loop in R for kNN

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, knn

I have made this customized k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm (k=1) that can also be used on categorical variables (char, string). However, in terms of performance, it's slow because it uses `for` loop. Is there a way to optimize this loop so that it can perform better?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test.data)) {
  a <- c(test.data[i,1:ncol(training.data)-1])

  final <- t((t(b) == a) * value)
  final[is.na(final)] <- 0
  sum.value <- rowSums(final)

  final1 <- cbind(training.data, sum.value)
  final1 <- final1[order(-sum.value),]
  final1 <- final1[final1$sum.value > 0,]

  suggestion <- unique(final1[,ncol(training.data)])

  if (length(unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val, ncol(training.data)])) < 5) {
    suggestion <- suggestion[1:5]
    output.line <- final1[!duplicated(final1$label),1:ncol(training.data)]
    output.line <- output.line[1:5,]
  } else {
    suggestion <- unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val, ncol(training.data)])
    output.line <- unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val,])
  }
  output <- rbind.fill(output,data.frame(t(c(test.ID = test.data[i,ncol(training.data),], suggestion))))

  sc <- t(t(output.line[,1:ncol(training.data)-1]) == a)
  sc[is.na(sc)] <- 0
  sc <- rowSums(sc)

  output.line <- cbind(output.line,sc)
  output.line <- rbind.fill(cbind(test.data[i,],sc = 0),output.line)
  output2 <- rbind(output2,output.line)
}
```

The variables are as follows:

```
training.data = ~21 columns of data (with numbers and strings)
test.data = ~20% of training.data
label = obviously the label column
b = training.data without the label column
```

This uses `plyr` package since it has `rbind.fill` function.

Hope you can help on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: indeed without digging to much into the code, you have at least to replace your for loop with an `*apply` function. You can also check the `foreach` package for parallel computing

Comment: also I guess you have a bug here: `1:ncol(training.data)-1` in your second line, because the `-1` applies to the vector not the value

Comment: I find it hard to use apply on this, but I'm trying. In terms of foreach and parallel computing, it runs almost the same latency as the original for loop. integrating the to Microsoft Azure Machine Learning is not allowed, so I crossed out this option.

Comment: `*apply` functions are a bit strange for people new to R but thing is if your loop applies the same operation to each "element" of your input, then indeed you "apply" a function of this element

Answer (score 0):

Not tested though it should do the job

```
output2 <- apply(test.data, 1, function(a) {
  final <- t((t(b) == a) * value)
  final[is.na(final)] <- 0
  sum.value <- rowSums(final)

  final1 <- cbind(training.data, sum.value)
  final1 <- final1[order(-sum.value),]
  final1 <- final1[final1$sum.value > 0,]

  suggestion <- unique(final1[,ncol(training.data)])

  if (length(unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val, ncol(training.data)])) < 5) {
    suggestion <- suggestion[1:5]
    output.line <- final1[!duplicated(final1$label),1:ncol(training.data)]
    output.line <- output.line[1:5,]
  } else {
    suggestion <- unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val, ncol(training.data)])
    output.line <- unique(training.data[sum.value == max.val,])
  }
  output <- rbind.fill(output,data.frame(t(c(a, suggestion))))

  sc <- t(t(output.line[,1:(ncol(training.data)-1)]) == a)
  sc[is.na(sc)] <- 0
  sc <- rowSums(sc)

  output.line <- cbind(output.line,sc)
  output.line <- rbind.fill(cbind(row,sc = 0),output.line)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @clemlaflemme for this! I'll try to simulate this on my end if this improved the performance of the former code.

Comment: Does this need to close the parenthesis, like this? `apply(test.data, 1, function(row))` or it must be opening bracket and close at the end of code, like this? `apply{test.data, 1, function(row)`

Comment: sure, close the parenthesis, I forgot. Edited now. Usage is `apply(test.data, 1, fun)`.

Comment: It displayed an error a while ago: `Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames`

Comment: is the current for loop working ? I can't figure out what you're trying to do after your if/else

Comment: The current loop seems working, but it triggers the error `All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames` on this point: `output.line <- rbind.fill(cbind(row,sc = 0),output.line)`

Comment: It seems that when I debugged the error, using the function `row`, when using `rbind.fill`, the data we're binding became a `list` instead of a `data.frame`.

Comment: `row` was a bad name indeed, in the edit I put `a` directly instead

Comment: `a` is used as a variable inside the loop. But upon changing it to `function(x)`, the error still persist. (The data we're binding became a `list` instead of a `data.frame`.)